# PlaySound() played but not hear c++

Tags: c++, speaker, playsound

I use playsound it work ok on my laptop but on my pc it's not working. When sound is playing I check volume scale it go up and down. But I can't hear any sound.

Note that my PC Speaker is using normal.

Comment: "SoundPlay"? From which library? We'll need some code, too.

Comment: So, your computer thinks it's playing sound, but you don't hear it?

Comment: Do you mean the winapi `PlaySound()`? Do other things such as `MessageBeep()` or `Beep()` work?

Comment: Beep is not working on my pc. MessageBeep is working on both device.